# SAS stack overflow: PROC SQL reading dictionary.columns

Tags: stack-overflow, sas

I have a program in which I am reading `dictionary.columns`. There is a big program with lot of code before and after the program segment in which I read `dictionary.column`.

The program used to work fine however it is giving error now. I have executed program 5 times it gave same error: `STACK Overflow`

However when I am executing same proc sql patch in different program it is executing fine.

Any suggestions on where the problem might be, and any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to fix stack overflow in SAS is just to close the session and start again. If you want to keep the datasets you created in the work folder, you can just go to the SAS Temporary Files folder (search for it, it's different on different machines, but it's usually located in Program Files/SAS Institute/... ). In the SAS Temporary Files folder you will find some TD_XXXX folders, the latest one probably contains your work library datasets.

Comment: You can find the location of the WORK directory by submitting `%put %sysfunc(getoption(work));`.